# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I'm using .net core v6 web api and hosted as docker container, its working fine in while running local iis but when i hosting in docker getting error like ;

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.   at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```
        StreamReader Reader;
        HttpWebRequest HttpRequest;
        HttpWebResponse HttpResponse;
        string ProviderResponse = "";
        try
        {

            HttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url + Request);
            HttpRequest.UserAgent = "useragent";
            HttpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            HttpRequest.Timeout = 60000;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls ;
           
            HttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpRequest.GetResponse();
            Reader = new StreamReader(HttpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            ProviderResponse = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            Reader.Close();
            HttpResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
           string error = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            
        }
```